# How to insert into TIMESTAMP Column Values in oracle using JDBC PreparedStatement

Tags: sql, oracle

```
String s1 = "create table crawler " +
            "(id number NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " +
            "url varchar(255) NOT NULL, " +
            "urlHash varchar(255) NOT NULL, " +
            "contentHash varchar(255), " +
            "modDate TIMESTAMP(4), " +
            "contentLocation varchar(100), " +
            "status integer, " +
            "lastCrawlDate TIMESTAMP(4)) ";




            String s2 = "create sequence test_seq start with 1 increment by 1 nomaxvalue";
            //String s3 = "create or replace trigger inserttrigger before insert on test for each row begin select test_seq.nextval into :new.id from dual; end;"; 

            stmt=conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(s1);
            stmt.executeUpdate(s2);
            //stmt.executeUpdate(s3);
```

**//How can I use TIMESTAMP here in this prepareStatement to add timestamp values in database as in Insert statement we can use like this  INSERT INTO mytimestamp (id, made_on) VALUES (1, TIMESTAMP '2005-05-13 07:15:31.123456789'); so how can I use this in prepareStatement.**

```
            ps = conn.prepareStatement (
            "INSERT INTO crawler (id, url, urlHash, contentHash, modDate, contentLocation, status, lastCrawlDate) VALUES(test_seq.nextval,?,?,?,TIMESTAMP '?',?,?,TIMESTAMP '?')");

            ps.setString (1, "http://www.google.com");
            ps.setString (2, "swerrsdfsfdgfgrgthtyty");
            ps.setString (3, "1a10407d9a7997531aabe");
            ps.setString (4, "2005-05-13 07:15:31.123456789");
            ps.setString (5, "c://");
            ps.setLong (6, 302);
            ps.setString (7, "2005-05-13 07:15:31.123456789");

            int count = ps.executeUpdate ();
```

This way I am getting error. Any wrong with this code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `TIMESTAMP '?'`, write `TO_TIMESTAMP(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')`.